# How to complete this circuit

Tags: electrical, wiring, led, battery

I got some decorative multi color led wire. It is broken at one place now. I need to connect the wire to complete the circuit. I am new to this and I am trying to learn. I tried twisting the wire so it would touch. But it didn't make the light to work. I tried twisting with aluminum foil also. It didn't work either. Please let me know how to connect these wires and whether these lights are of any specific types of led. What wire is this? Lead? 
[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, electronics repair and soldering is off-topic here.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I won't post these sort of questions here.

Answer (score 3):

Small colored wires like this have an enamel coating that insulates the wire so that it does not short out to other wires or metal objects/surfaces. It is this coating that is making it so that you cannot just twist the wires together to complete the circuit.

The conventional way to rejoin wires of this ilk is to twist and solder. But first it will be necessary to very carefully scrape enamel coating off the surface of the wire using a sharp utility knife blade or safety razor blade.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the information. It makes sense now

Comment: ED's answer is educational and very correct, and both of the answers (this one and his) joined give great information.

Comment: I've had good luck removing enamel insulation coating by placing an ordinary aspirin tablet outside, adding a bit of solder flux and heating it with the wire in place. It was then a simple matter to tin the wire for the project to continue.

Answer (score 2):

LED's have a polarity if you connected them up backwards it would not work. LED's emit light in reverse bias mode and act as a diode in the forward bias mode. Hopefully when you hooked it up there was enough of a load on the string to limit the current or it may have blown the junction. Reverse bias the breakdown voltage is usually +1.2v in forward bias breakdown is ~.6v so if the current wasent limited the lower voltage breakdown allows more current flow and the magic smoke escapes. Twisting the leads should work if not plastic coated.

Comment: This answer is great for some bacground info. It's useful to note that with a DVOM (a basic digital volt ohm meter) they often have a diode test function. Some LED's are specifically built to be bipolor, he may have a bipolar led. However, current limits still need to be observed. (His device might use AC). Just using a meter, test the LED like Ed notes, and like Karas notes, clean the surface to allow soldering, then tape it off or heat shrink to protect the now exposed wires. Perhaps your kit has these instructions?